# Logging can't happen in one project (NSLogs are not working)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode10.1

My NSLogs are not displayed in console only for that project, For other projects, it is working fine. Can anybody help regarding what changes been made in Project settings?

but what I figure out that when I remove DEBUG=1 from Build Setting it works but when I put it again, it does not working

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the All Output/Target Output is selected in the log area. If the debugger output is selected then there would not be any logs.

The log section in Xcode below should NOT look like this.

[image]

This can be one of the issues. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am testing this in ALL Outputs only.

Comment: On which iOS version you are testing?

Comment: on ios 12.2, but what I figure out that when I remove DEBUG=1 from Build Setting it works but when I put it again, it does not working.